# PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null, null) FlutterActivity Local_auth

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an application that needs 2 plugins, the first is the flutter_barcode_scanner plugin and the other is local_auth.
I am aware that the 'local_auth' plugin uses the FlutterFragmentActivity class instead of FlutterActivity.

My problem is that I can't use the flutter_barcode_scanner plugin when I implement my MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity class.

I tried using the channel method to switch calls, but it didn't work.

what else can I try?

My code :

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri; 





public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.quadrant.procon_uberlandia_fiscalizacao";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if (call.method.equals("callFlutterFragmentActivity")) {
                                // Call a method in FlutterFragmentActivity and send the result back to Flutter.
                               // Start FlutterFragmentActivity.
                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlutterFragmentActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                                result.success("FlutterFragmentActivity started");
                                // Call the method in FlutterFragmentActivity.
                                result.success("Method in FlutterFragmentActivity called");
                            } else if (call.method.equals("callFlutterActivity")) {
                                // Call a method in FlutterActivity and send the result back to Flutter.
                                FlutterActivity flutterActivity = new FlutterActivity();
                                
                                // Call the method in FlutterActivity.
                                result.success("Method in FlutterActivity called");
                            } else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

```
<activity 
         android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I tried calling FlutterFragmentActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file too, but it didn't work, it returned the following message in debug mode:
PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null, null)